# Formatting PSCustomObject for conversion to JSON

Tags: json, powershell

I'm attempting to create a PSCustomObject that will later be piped through `ConvertTo-JSON`, but I can't seem to get the formatting of the PSCustomObject quite right. The issue seems to be that the way I want my resultant JSON to be formatted includes a jagged array, but the proper Powershell syntax eludes me.

**Here's what I have**

```
$RetrievalParamsBodyObj = [PSCustomObject]@{
    things = @(@{
                field="date_created"
                operator="within"
                value="7"
            })
    }
```

When I pass that through `ConvertTo-JSON`, it looks like this:

```
$RetrievalParamsBodyObj | ConvertTo-JSON
{
    "things": [
        {
             "field":  "date_created",
             "operator":  "within",
             "value":  "7"
         }
     ]
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{
    "things": [
        [{
            "field": "date_created",
            "operator": "within last",
            "value": "7"
        }]
    ]
}
```

I've tried wrapping an additional array around the hash table, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two tricks: 1) preface the internal array with a comma so Powershell knows it's a nested array instead of a concatenated one, and 2) make sure to set the Depth:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    things = @(,@(@{
                field="date_created"
                operator="within"
                value="7"
            }))
    } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
```

Output:

```
{
    "things":  [
                   [
                       {
                           "field":  "date_created",
                           "operator":  "within",
                           "value":  "7"
                       }
                   ]
               ]
}
```

... which is syntactically identical to your desired output. To get it formatted differently you would need to create a custom JSON serializer.

Comment: +1, though note that you don't need the outer `@(...)` at all, and you could replace the inner `@(...)` with yet another unary `,`. Ultimately, the confusion stems from mistaking `@(...)` for an array _construction_ operator, whereas it is a mere array "guarantor".